# Finding the number of matching elements in 2 arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently doing an exercise from a textbook (not a homework, self-study) that given the correct answers for a multiple choice exam, which I named answerKey, ask the user to input the answers from the student, and find the matching elements to calculate grade. Please see what I had done so far. What I don't understand is the behavior of numCount, on why it does not return correctly. I would like guidance on this. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Drivers_License
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int incorrect = 0;
        double grade = 0.0;
        String input;
        char[] answerKey = {'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C',
                            'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D',
                            'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D',
                            'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A'};
        System.out.println();

        int numCorrect = 0;
        int total = 0;
        char[] responses = new char[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter answer for # %d: ", i+1);
            responses[i] = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim().charAt(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < answerKey.length; j++) {
                if (responses[i] == (answerKey[j])) {
                    System.out.println(responses[i]);
                    numCorrect++; // I don't quite understand
                                  // what is happening here...
                }
            }
        }

        /* Display elements in userAnswers array */
        System.out.println("User answers are below");
        for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(responses[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


$ java Drivers_License

Enter answer for # 1: a
Enter answer for # 2: b
Enter answer for # 3: c
Enter answer for # 4: d
Enter answer for # 5: a
Enter answer for # 6: b
Enter answer for # 7: c
Enter answer for # 8: d
Enter answer for # 9: a
Enter answer for # 10: b
Enter answer for # 11: c
Enter answer for # 12: d
Enter answer for # 13: a
Enter answer for # 14: b
Enter answer for # 15: c
Enter answer for # 16: d
Enter answer for # 17: a
Enter answer for # 18: b
Enter answer for # 19: c
Enter answer for # 20: d
No. of correct answers: 100
User answers are below
A B C D A B C D A B C D A B C D A B C D
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I would like a detailed explanation on what is happening right now with what I have written. Maybe if I understand the mechanics of the nested for loops, I could figure out what I need. Thank you all!

Comment: I can't find any numCount = 120 in the code or the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two for loops (one inside another). These are nested for loops.
What is happening in the above code is that for each index i in the first array, all the j's in the second array are visited.

What you want to do is have just one for loop (of 20 iterations) and access elements from both the arrays in parallel.

```
    public class Drivers_License
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int incorrect = 0;
        double grade = 0.0;
        String input;
        char[] answerKey = {'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C',
                            'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D',
                            'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D',
                            'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A'};
        System.out.println();

        int total = 0;
        char[] responses = new char[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter answer for # %d: ", i+1);
            responses[i] = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim().charAt(0);

        }

        int numCorrect = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
           if (responses[i] == (answerKey[i])) { // Look here
                System.out.println(responses[i]);
                numCorrect++;
            }
        }

        /* Display elements in userAnswers array */
        System.out.println("User answers are below");
        for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(responses[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: _"for each index i in the first array, all the j's in the second array are visited."_ So, how many times do the j's in the second array get visited? 5 times per one i?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `break` statement inside your nested loop (the one with `j` as an integer) whenever you get a correct answer.

```
for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter answer for # %d: ", i+1);
            responses[i] = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim().charAt(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < answerKey.length; j++) {
                if (responses[i] == (answerKey[j])) {
                    System.out.println(responses[i]);
                    numCorrect++; 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The `break` will take you out of the loop and will move to the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the break option. Actually, I thought of an inefficient way to find the correct count of answers. What I have right now that works is having a nested for loop after asking the user for input. This gives the correct number of numCount but it's a bit cluttered.

Comment: I can help you with that too, but why don't you try it first :)